# How to increase heap size of Android Application?

Tags: android

> Hi, I am performing animation in android application. When running the my application is crash and getting OutOfMemoryException. The error are,
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 9437196 byte allocation with 3044192 free bytes and 2MB until OOM

I tried to add largeHeap=true statement in my manifeast file, but this is not the right solution. So, please help me for solving this above problem. Thank you.

My Logcat are given below,

```
8:05.256 9298-9298/ayurjanaapp.dell.xerces.com.ayurjnanaapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          Process: ayurjanaapp.dell.xerces.com.ayurjnanaapp, PID: 9298
          java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 9437196 byte allocation with 3044192 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
              at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
              at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
              at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2638)
              at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2543)
              at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
              at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:162)
              at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:150)
              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1013)
              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1072)
              at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
              at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
              at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:512)
              at ayurjanaapp.dell.xerces.com.ayurjnanaapp.AnimationForSubsequentBellsActivity.showBellDialog(AnimationForSubsequentBellsActivity.java:41)
              at ayurjanaapp.dell.xerces.com.ayurjnanaapp.AnimationForSubsequentBellsActivity.onCreate(AnimationForSubsequentBellsActivity.java:31)
              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
  12-05 10:4
```

Comment: I added this statement in my gradle file.

Comment: No, I am not creating Application class

Comment: @Vadivel What? This has nothing to do with Apache HTTP

Comment: From the exceptions stack trace I can see that you are loading a very large Drawable resource, its not the animation thats causing the OOM its the large drawable decoding

Comment: Also relevant - https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: ok I am trying your solution.

Comment: The solution of using Application class is not worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue by adding `largeHeap = "true"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Hope this helps.

Comment: I already added this statement in manifeast file

Comment: Dude there's no guarantee how much large heap will be and sometimes it doesn't work...!